# Quickly discover differences between two SQL server databases

Tags: sql-server, database, compare

Is there a nice tool that allows for easy comparison between 2 Sql-Server databases ?

For example, I'd like to do dev DB vs. live DB comparison to see what objects 
(view, stored procedures, tables ...) have been modified in dev.

I know I can just run a script that compares system files, but I am hoping there is something nicer out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's lots of options:

Red Gate SQL Compare is my favorite, but ApexSQL has one (SQL Diff) as well.  Also, Nob Hill Software has one.

Comment: SQL Compare is worth every penny.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB has a way to dump its definitions without the data to a text file, the diff tool would be a low tech way to solve this.

Might not be ideal, but all the tools you need will very often already be installed on your server.

Short answer as I'm on the phone, sorry.